# Search Result does not update instantly flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm emulating this [search and filter github](https://github.com/JohannesMilke/filter_listview_example) here and the codes are almost the same but the filtered results do not update instantly while I type and also I faced the following issues:

1. I will have to press enter on my laptop to finally get the filtered list
2. When I hit the close icon(which is to clear all the words), I will have to tap the `searchbar` again so that all my `listtile` are back on the listview.

Here's my code:

```js
class _CurrencySelectState extends State<CurrencySelect> {
  late List<Currency> resCur;
  String query = '';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    resCur = currencyList;
  }

void searchCur(String query) {
      final List<Currency> filteredCur = currencyList.where((cur) {
        final symbolLower = cur.symbol.toLowerCase(); // Search using symbol
        final nameLower = cur.country.toLowerCase(); // Search using country
        final searchLower = query.toLowerCase();

        return symbolLower.contains(searchLower) ||
            nameLower.contains(searchLower);
      }).toList();

      setState(() {
        this.query = query;
        resCur = filteredCur;
      });
    }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    Widget buildCur(Currency cur) => ListTile(
      leading: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInset.all(5)
        child: SizedBox(
          child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                SvgPicture.asset(
                  cur.assetPath,
                ),
              ]),
        ),
      ),
      title: Column(
        children: [
          Text(
            cur.symbol,
            style: TextStyle(
                ...
          ),
          Text(
            cur.name,
            style: TextStyle(
                ...
          ),
        ],
      ),
      trailing: Text(
        "0.25",
        style: TextStyle(
            ...
      ),
    );

    return TextButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          showModalBottomSheet(
              enableDrag: false,
              context: context,
              isScrollControlled: true,
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return DraggableScrollableSheet(
                  expand: false,
                  builder: (context, scrollController) {
                    return Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        SearchWidget(
                            text: query,
                            onChanged: searchCur,
                            hintText: "Enter symbol or country"
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: ListView.builder(
                            controller: scrollController,
                            itemCount: resCur.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
                              final cur = resCur[index];
                              return buildCur(cur);
                            },
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    );
                  },
                );
              });
        },
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: [
            Text(
              ...
            ),
            SvgPicture.asset(
              ...
            )
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

Searchwidget code:

```js
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SearchWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final String text;
  final ValueChanged<String> onChanged;
  final String hintText;

  const SearchWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.text,
    required this.onChanged,
    required this.hintText,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SearchWidgetState createState() => _SearchWidgetState();
}

class _SearchWidgetState extends State<SearchWidget> {
  final controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final styleActive = TextStyle(color: Colors.black);
    final styleHint = TextStyle(color: Colors.black54);
    final style = widget.text.isEmpty ? styleHint : styleActive;

    return Container(
      height: 42,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16, 16, 16, 16),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
        color: Colors.white,
        border: Border.all(color: Colors.black26),
      ),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
      child: TextField(
        controller: controller,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          icon: Icon(Icons.search, color: style.color),
          suffixIcon: widget.text.isNotEmpty
              ? GestureDetector(
                  child: Icon(Icons.close, color: style.color),
                  onTap: () {
                    controller.clear();
                    widget.onChanged('');
                    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
                  },
                )
              : null,
          hintText: widget.hintText,
          hintStyle: style,
          border: InputBorder.none,
        ),
        style: style,
        onChanged: widget.onChanged,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: please share the code where you have implemented you searchCur .... or you should consider using a textEditingController to track changes and do accordingly

Comment: @AnkitKumarMaurya `searchCur` function is inside the code, I've added SearchWidget class just in case you want to see it,